# Windows Phone Navigation to code error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm a new member to stackoverflow. I'm trying to create a windows phone 8.0 mp3 player with c#. I have downloaded the background audio player sample from Microsoft samples page. I have used the code to build my mp3 player app. Incase you would like to reference the code , follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx .However, when I try to build my app, I'm getting this error.

```
Error   1   'dj_mxx_player.Player.OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override    C:\Users\dansyo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\dj mxx player\dj mxx player\Player.xaml.cs    23  33  dj mxx player
```

This is the code which is giving me the above error.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (PlayState.Playing == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
            {
                BitmapImage ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images/play.png", UriKind.Relative));
                pause.Source = ImageSource;
                a1.Text = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track.Title + "By";
                a2.Text = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track.Artist;
            }
            else
            {
                BitmapImage ImageS = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images/pause.png", UriKind.Relative));
                pause.Source = ImageS;
                a1.Text = " ";
                a2.Text = " ";
            }
        }
```

Please help me solve out this issue. THANKS

Comment: share the full sample in onedrive i will try to solve it and give

Comment: Hi  SD7, I have managed to solve out the case . Thanks